# openfortivpn - Could not authenticate to gateway (Bad HTTP response code)

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I'd like to connect to a company's `VPN` network and then to connect to remote
desktop via `RDP` (`remmina` or something else, it doesn't matter).

After I did [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226364/how-to-connect-ssl-vpn-on-ubuntu-18-04/1338207#1338207) steps with configuration (`/etc/openfortivpn/config`)

```
host=193.175.62.8
port=10443
username=yes
password=pass
trusted-cert=9154b30de37d7967ffe956d7993291c85390cb76c506feba708e981e0ca8806f
```

We don't use certificate so, I have taken that from an error message (as in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWGzt2b1fYk) video).

After
`sudo openfortivpn`

I have this error message

```
INFO:   Connected to gateway.
ERROR:  Could not authenticate to gateway (Bad HTTP response code).
INFO:   Closed connection to gateway.
INFO:   Logged out.
```

Could you please troubleshoot me to be able to connect to remote desktop in the end?

Comment: The response code from the server was bad - you have to coordinate with your workplace IT team to try and get connected, there's not enough information here for *us* to help you troubleshoot this.  Only the workplace IT team can assist.

Comment: @ThomasWard Isn't there something like debugging? The IP address, port, username and password should be certainly good.

Comment: the only error message you're getting there is you got a bad HTTP response code.  You *might* be able to find a debugging option in openfortivpn (check its manpage) but if the debug options don't yield a result then it's likely that you still need to coordinate with the Workplace because they actually control the VPN server side of things.  They may not *want* you to have access remotely from your computer, or may only issue VPN with extra restrictions to certain company issued machines

Comment: @ThomasWard I tried `sudo openfortivpn --pppd-log=jop.txt` but it didn't created the file `jop.txt`.

Comment: Don't use the log function use `-vv` as flags to openfortivpn - `sudo openfortivpn -vv` and then grab the output.  Sanitize specific information but you might be missing critical information (certs, user certificates, etc. which add security to the connection - if you can't connect without a certificate like I suspect, you will need to work with the workplace IT team)

Comment: @ThomasWard [Here](https://pastebin.com/364dYDNe) is the output. There is problem with the certificate, but network admin said to me, they don't use certificate. So, I used the "trick" as in [the youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWGzt2b1fYk).

Comment: any solution ? any way to ignore it?